# on a piano app vs in a piano app

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

1) I was learning to play a song on a piano app.

2) I was learning to play a song in a piano app.

Which one correct is correct  and why?

Comment: What about "using a piano app"?

Comment: Or ***with*** *a piano app*. (I wouldn't choose either of the prepositions in the question.)